# I don't know exactly what I'm trying to find

Tags: mysql, sql

Have no clue how to go around this, but I do know it's possible, at least I think it is. I tried googling various terms that sound like they would make sense i.e "how to mark something as taken in sql" or "How to track if a customer has a rented item in sql". I've kind of hit a wall here I don't even know what it's called that im looking for or how to go about it.

I have my 3 tables that I feel are needed for this project (its a rental site) for MySQL I have a `rental`, `customer`, and a `video` table. The rental table takes information from both the customer and the video table to see who has rented an item and when it's due.

How do I make it so that if one customer rents a video another can't rent the same video? Could someone please point me in the right direction so I can further my googling?

**Customer table:**

idCustomer | first_name | last_name | phone_number

**Video table:**

idVideo | title | genera | rent_price

**Rental table:**

idRental | idCustomer | idVideo | rent_date | due_date | return_date

I'm wondering if its possible to add a column that can track if a video is already rented or not? Is that a thing?

Comment: Could you update your question with the structure of those tables and possible what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm new here and added a edit :)

Comment: Hi. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In your rental table, you do already see if a video is taken and for how long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the rental table, you can create a query that would provide you the required information by using the `return_date` of the rental.

For example, if you would like to see a list of all the videos available for rental, the following query woudld be:

```
SELECT * FROM video v
WHERE idVideo NOT IN (SELECT idVideo FROM rental r WHERE v.idVideo = r.idVideo AND r.return_date < CAST(NOW() AS DATE))
```

Or for those which are currently rented out:

```
SELECT * FROM video v
WHERE idVideo IN (SELECT idVideo FROM rental r WHERE v.idVideo = r.idVideo r.return_date >= CAST(NOW() AS DATE))
```